# Aggregation Parsing in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a working elasticsearch query, but I can't figure out how to parse the return value using the java API. It seems no matter which way I configure it, I run into a null value.

The query in elastisearch is:

```
GET user_profile/active_time/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggregations" : {
    "agg1" : {
      "filter" : {
        "range" : {
          "timestamp" : {
            "from" : 0,
            "to" : 1501786179177,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "agg2" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "userId",
            "size" : 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It produces the return value:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 55,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "agg1": {
      "doc_count": 55,
      "agg2": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 0,
            "doc_count": 34
          },
          {
            "key": 295,
            "doc_count": 12
          },
          {
            "key": 59,
            "doc_count": 3
          },
          {
            "key": 764,
            "doc_count": 3
          },
          {
            "key": 788,
            "doc_count": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering how to correctly get the buckets out of aggregation 2. In a previous iteration, I was able to access it using

`Terms terms = sr.getProperty("agg2");`

But the filter didn't work in that case. Should I reformat my query or is there some way to parse this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By moving the range filter out of the aggregation and into a normal search, I was able to parse the values using these lines.

```
Terms terms = sr.getAggregations().get("agg");
Collection<Terms.Bucket> buckets = terms.getBuckets();
for (Terms.Bucket x : buckets) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + x.getKey() + " Count: " + x.getDocCount());
}
```

Here's the new query:

```
GET user_profile/active_time/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": 0,
        "lte": 1501786179177
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggregations" : {
    "agg1" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "userId",
            "size" : 0
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the result of the query is stored in a variable named "results", you can do:

```
for i in results["aggregations"]["agg1"]["agg2"]["buckets"]:
   key = i["key"]
   doc_count = i["doc_count"]
```

This is in Python, hopefully the Java way is similar.